# How to reference module files with Puppet?

Tags: puppet

I know that Puppet has first-class support for referencing module templates with the `template` function and now I find myself trying to find support for referencing module files. I was expecting that `file('foomodule/barfile')` or even `file('foomodule/files/barfile')` would correctly reference `modules/foomodule/files/barfile`, wherever the module may be located, but I seem to be forced into providing the fully qualified path to the file.

The reference documentation for the [`file`](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#file) function unfortunately doesn't provide any hints on how this can be accomplished, though I'm assuming there should be some elegant way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this ?

```
file { "some_file" :
   source =>"puppet:///modules/foomodule/barfile",
   owner  => "root",
   .....
}
```

`puppet:///modules` check the `modulepath (/etc/puppet/module)` in my case. The bar file will be located in

```
/etc/puppet/module/foomodule/files/barfile
```

Comment: While this may work, as far as I understand this would leave out users that wish to provision locally without a master catalog.

Comment: Old question, but FWIW - no, the URLs work during `puppet apply` as well. They will **not** work for an agent that applies a cached catalog that *was* received from a master. (Supporting this edge case is often not worthwile.)